# Two setUp() functions in python unit testing, one that runs for every test, one that only runs once

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have just starting using unittesting, I want some code to run for every test (which is how the default setUp() seems to work) but I want some code to just run once, right at the beginning of the run, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should define a [`setUpClass` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`setUpClass`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.setUpClass) which runs once to set up the test class. It runs before the test methods in that class are executed:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    pass
```